# Can we use QM-AM inequality to solve this?

Tags: inequality

There are two sequences (${a_1,a_2,a_3,....,a_n })$ and $( {b_1,b_2,b_3,....,b_n})$ 
 such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$$

Prove that:
          $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{a_i+b_i} \ge \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$

P.S I can do it with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the Engel form. But can you do it with QM-AM Inequality? I saw somebody do it [here](https://youtu.be/Tf6aMTnglyI?list=PL018X5Hlr4Rl4Eim90G_LRC0QjKAQg-d1). I cannot understand it.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you make it?

Comment: But you can up vote it Michael. @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Shouldn't the right-hand side be $\frac12\sum_{i=1}^na_i$? This question isn't from IMO 1991 either (unless the I doesn't stand for international).

Comment: QM is quadratic mean?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for each $i$ we have $$\frac{a_i^2}{a_i+b_i}- \frac{b_i^2}{a_i+b_i} = a_i-b_i$$

so $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{a_i+b_i} =    \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i^2}{a_i+b_i}$$

By Qm-Am inequality we have for each $i$, : $$\frac{a_i^2}{a_i+b_i}+ \frac{b_i^2}{a_i+b_i}= \frac{a_i^2+b_i^2}{a_i+b_i} \geq \frac{{1\over 2}(a_i+b_i)^2}{a_i+b_i} =    {1\over 2}(a_i+b_i)$$

Does this help?

Comment: So you decided that this is unacceptable.